# enabling a button when a button is clicked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on jQuery and I am rendering a graph. In that I have scrollable arrows on both right and left side of the graph. My requested functionality is:

- Whenever the data is more and whenever we click the right arrow automatically the left scrollable arrow must be visible.
- If there is not more data, the right button must be invisible.
- If there is not enough data for scrolling, the left button must be invisible.
- To sum up: buttons should only be available, if they can be used.

here is my code so far:

```
$(function() {
    var $box2 = $('.column'), totalWidth = 900, cursor = 0;

    $("#rightarrrowbutton").click(function() {
        if (cursor != totalWidth) {
            $box2.animate({
                marginLeft : "-=15"
            }, "fast");
            cursor += 100;
        }
    });
    if ($("#rightarrowbutton").click(){
        $('#leftarrowbutton').click(function() {
            if (cursor != 0) {
                $box2.animate({
                    marginLeft : "+=15"
                }, "fast");
                cursor -= 100;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Off Topic: Is your shift key broken?

Comment: `if ($("#rightarrowbutton").click(function(){//....` this is always true, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like

```
$("#rightarrrowbutton").click(function() {
 $("#leftarrowbutton").show();  
 });

  $("#leftarrowbutton").click(function() {
 $("#rightarrrowbutton").show();

  });
```

Comment: You need to check after clicking the right arrow whether or not there's more stuff to show, and if there isn't, hide the right arrow. Same for the left.

Comment: thank you Deepak. i have added the $("#leftarrowbutton").hide(); on top of the function. and also this $("#rightarrrowbutton").click(function() {
 $("#leftarrowbutton").show();  
 }); after the rightarrow button function. it worked perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to attach and remove click handlers, just add them when you page loads and `.hide()` or `.show()` your buttons as appropriate.

```
$('#rightarrowbutton').click() {
    // do your stuff
    if (/*there's no more stuff to the right*/) {
        $('#rightarrowbutton').hide();
    }
    $('#leftarrowbutton').show();
}
```

and similar for the left button.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Matt. but the thing is that when my right arrow is pressed automatically my left arrow should be enabled. if not it must be hidden

Comment: @HkM: Errm...yeah, this makes the left arrow visible when the right arrow is clicked. So I don't understand your complaint.

Comment: i got the solution Matt. thank you very much for your response

Answer (score 0):

I know your description talks about visibility, but the title of your question mentions enabling.  To disable, you can put the attribute `"disabled"` in the `<button>` element.  If there, it will be disabled, if missing it will be enabled.  So you could remove or add the property during the `.click()` callback.

For example:

```
$("#leftarrowbutton").click(function ()
{
    // if meets ending criteria
    if (true)
    {
        // enable other button
        $("#rightarrowbutton").removeAttr("disabled");

        // disable current button
        $("#leftarrowbutton").attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```